# How to create this type of in app rating directly from play store in flutter?

Tags: flutter, rating

how can i create this type of rating provide from google in flutter ?
[image]

**Note**
i don't want to open play store then rate my app i want dialog like this to rate my app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[in_app_review](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_review) package works pretty good for this

All you just need to do is

```
import 'package:in_app_review/in_app_review.dart';

final InAppReview inAppReview = InAppReview.instance;

if (await inAppReview.isAvailable()) {
    inAppReview.requestReview();
}
```

Check official doc for better understanding